# How to determine what the GET parameters are/were from the previous URL when redirected to a new domain

Tags: php, https, http-headers, mollie

I am trying to retrieve the request header (I do not want to modify it) and see what the GET parameters were by retrieving the `:path` property. I have read on StackOverflow and other websites about it, but no concrete answer was ever given as to whether this is possible or not. So hereby the question: Is it possible and if so, how? I have access to both domains in the sense of: I can modify code if required.

So as an example, let's say I go from `domainA.com?p=q` to `domainB.com`. In `domainB.com` I'd like to know what URL with `GET` parameters sent the user to `domainB.com`. In `domainB.com` I'd like to retrieve all the GET from `domainA.com` or flat out the `:path` property. I wish to do something like `window.history.back()`, but either by sending the user back to `domainA.com` or by retrieving the URL with GET parameters.

***Edit***

```
    $this->provider = new \Mollie\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Mollie([
        'clientId'     => 'XXXXXXX',
        'clientSecret' => 'XXXXX',
        'redirectUri'  => 'https://example.com/oauth',
    ]);

        if (!isset($_GET['code']))
        {
            // Fetch the authorization URL from the provider; this returns the
            // urlAuthorize option and generates and applies any necessary parameters
            // (e.g. state).
            $authorizationUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl([
                // Optional, only use this if you want to ask for scopes the user previously denied.
                'approval_prompt' => 'auto', 
                
                // Optional, a list of scopes. Defaults to only 'organizations.read'.
                'scope' => [
                    \Mollie\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Mollie::SCOPE_PAYMENTS_READ,
                    \Mollie\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Mollie::SCOPE_PAYMENTS_WRITE,
                    \Mollie\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Mollie::SCOPE_REFUNDS_READ,
                    \Mollie\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Mollie::SCOPE_REFUNDS_WRITE,
                    \Mollie\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Mollie::SCOPE_PROFILES_READ,
                    \Mollie\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Mollie::SCOPE_PROFILES_WRITE,
                    \Mollie\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Mollie::SCOPE_ONBOARDING_READ,
                    \Mollie\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Mollie::SCOPE_ORGANIZATIONS_READ,
                    \Mollie\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Mollie::SCOPE_ORGANIZATIONS_WRITE
                ], 
            ]);
        
            // Get the state generated for you and store it to the session.
            $_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $provider->getState();
        
            // Redirect the user to the authorization URL.
            header('Location: ' . "{$authorizationUrl}&return={$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}"); 
            exit;
        }
```

authorizationUrl, when the user clicks approve it sends them to the redirectUri defined in the provider
it sends you to the redurectUri like this: https://example.com/oauth?code=xxx

Comment: You can't, unless you forward/include the data in the URL to domainB. An HTTP request only contains what it contains, there's no "history" or anything else available, unless *you* store and/or pass the data somehow.

Comment: So there is no way to retrieve the :path property from the request header for example? The reason I am asking is because my validation end-point is called from the Oauth page, which would be domainB. Now I am trying to send the user back to domainA from domainB.

Comment: That's what you include a `?return` parameter or similar for usually…

Comment: I do such thing, the problem however: The payment provider demands a redirectUri, which cannot have any appended parameters, since it's hardcoded. I can put a ?return in the Oauth part, but once it sends me to the redirectUri, it removes all of this. I can however see that the ?return is there in the request header its :path property

Comment: [Edit] your question to give us a [mre] and we can maybe help you with that…

Comment: I editted the question to the best I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions when dealing with Oauth and an end-point which is a different website (which you have access to and in which you can modify code).

The first one is to set the `state` parameter and provide your website URL. In my case it can be achieved through `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]`. This is passed back to your `redirect-uri`. You could also choose to use the so called `referer` header, which tells you what domain/server requested the page.